# C# - Windows Store App - How to sort a List<JsonObject>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, windows-store-apps

My App has a `List<T>` of `JsonObject`'s and I want to be able to sort them.

My `JsonObject`'s are derived from something similar to

```
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"isAlive": true,
"age": 25,
"height_cm": 167.64,
"address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
},
"phoneNumbers": [
    { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
    { "type": "fax",  "number": "646 555-4567" }
]
}
```

I'm fairly new to C# and .NET and started writing a sort algorithm

```
        public  List<JsonObject> SortAgeAsc(List<JsonObject> data)
        {
            List<JsonObject> sorted = new List<JsonObject>();
            // Iterate through each object and sort into age order
            foreach(JsonObject jo in data)
            {
                bool added = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < sorted.Count; i++)
                {
                    // If our data object has a lower age then the current sorted object, add it in its place.
                    if(jo.GetNamedNumber("age") <= sorted.ElementAt(i).GetNamedNumber("age"))
                    {
                        sorted.Insert(i, jo);
                        added = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If we are yet to add it, it must be the oldest so far. 
                if (!added)
                    sorted.Add(jo);
            }
            return sorted;
        }
```

NOTE: Please don't comment about whether or not this is an efficient sort or not, as that's beyond the scope of this question.

I then started reading about `List<T>.Sort()` and thought there must be way use that instead of writing the sort algorithm myself, as I would hope it was an efficient way of sorting.

Most examples I came across used class properties to sort on. Is there a way I can sort my `List<JsonObject>`on a particular json key (like "age" in my example above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out for myself.

To sort any `List` (rather then ordering a list), you need to have an `IComparer` interface, so the `Sort()` method can call compare on two instances of your `Type`.

`JsonObject`'s are a list of key value pair's, where the value can be one 6 different `JsonValueType`'s (bool, number, string, JsonObject, null, array). So when doing a compare, you need to take this fact into account and handle any instances of type mismatch.

Here's an `IComparer` that can sort a `List<JsonObject>` on a key that should have a number as a value.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A comparere class for sorting JsonObject lists on given key
    /// number values. Ascending.
    /// </summary>
    private class NumberComparerAsc : IComparer<JsonObject>
    {
        private string key;
        public NumberComparerAsc(string key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public int Compare(JsonObject x, JsonObject y)
        {
            int result = -1;
            IJsonValue xValue = null;
            IJsonValue yValue = null;
            x.TryGetValue(key, out xValue);
            y.TryGetValue(key, out yValue);

            if (xValue != null && yValue != null)
            {
                // If they are both number do a compare.
                if (xValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Number && yValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Number)
                {
                    result = xValue.GetNumber().CompareTo(yValue.GetNumber());
                }
                else
                {
                    // If x is a number, it is less they y.
                    if (xValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Number)
                    {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                    // If y is a number, x is greater then y
                    else if (y.ValueType == JsonValueType.Number)
                    {
                        result = 1;
                    }
                    // If neither are a number they are equal
                    else
                    {
                        result = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (xValue == null)
                {
                    // x is less then y.
                    result = -1;
                }
                else if (yValue == null)
                {
                    // x is greater then y.
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // x and y are equal
                    result = 0;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This is how you would use it in the context of my original question.

```
...
List<JsonObject> users = GetUsers();
users.Sort(new NumberComparerAsc("age"))
...
```

That will sort the list into an ascending numerical order on the "age" key. If any of the values that have the key "age" don't happen to be of `JsonValueType.Number` then they will be at the bottom of the list in what ever order they were already in the list.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this using **OrderBy**:

```
var sorted = data.OrderBy(x=>x.age).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you edit that to use a `JsonObject`? JsonObject does not have an `age` property. You have to get the age by calling `JsonObject.GetNamedNumber("age")`. And an explanation would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: you have to deserialze json to a class type and then orderby it,,see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371122/sorting-a-json-object-using-linq

Comment: `JsonOject` is deserilaized JSON. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx)